# Does executeUpdate on a delete query in hibernate deletes that object from session too

Tags: hibernate

I am deleting an object using

```
session.createQuery("delete Sample sample where sampleId = :sampleId")
.setInteger(sampleId,1).executeUpdate();
```

This gives me number of rows deleted as `1` which is correct.
But when I fetch this object from session using the object's id it gives me a non null value.

So deleting the object using `session.delete()` isn't similar to above query.

Comment: Record will not be deleted from DB untill you commit the transaction.

Comment: I have committed the transaction but its still there in session.

Comment: Any updates on answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Session.delete(...)` is only useful if you already have a reference to the entity you want to delete.

`delete-by-query` is useful for deleting several objects according to certain criteria, objects that you may not have previously loaded into the session.

I think that delete-by-query actually loads each entity into the session and deletes them individually.

That means if you execute query then hibernate will load that object into session and then delete it from DB so after `executeUpdate();` if you dont flush `session` and tried to `get` the object it will return non-null value. where as `session.delete()` will delete it and flush the session (if `FlushMode`  is on auto). in both cases DB will be get reflected after transaction commit.

But if you observe console by keeping `show-sql` true then on `delete()` you will find that it will first execute `select` then `delete` if that object is present in DB if that object is not present in DB then on `select` get excuted.

Read More @ http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-basics-3-ways-to-delete-an-entity-from-the-datastore

Comment: session.delete() behaves according to hibernate oobject state i.e Transient,Persistent and Detached.

Comment: Thanks Amogh for the detailed explanation. session.flush() helped actually.

Comment: I understand you for saying Tank you but according to StackOverflow standers "Please do not add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you". " Marking as answer will able to understand ;), Read More @ http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers